# Is Firefox 4 multi-core optimized?

Tags: multi-core, firefox

I've been reading about Multi-Core support in Firefox. There are outdated https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Status Wiki pages. Which states "Firefox should be Multi-Core aware in 2 years", which is now. So I am wondering if Firefox 4, for the Desktop, is optimized for Multi-Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. Firefox doesn't have any specific ways of utilising multi-core, although I imagine that this isn't a significant problem for most usage scenarios these days, it might be more important in the future.

Robert O' Callahan has blogged about this a bit before:
http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2006/12/parallelism_1.html, http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2007/09/parallel_dom_ac.html

Or I recommend the [WaterFox Project](http://www.overclock.net/other-software/975626-waterfox-firefox-4-64-bit-4-a.html) (Firefox with MMX, SSE2 and x64 favoring enabled)

More news, if any, will be found here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Roadmap